# ValueError: time data '30 avr. 2020 23:19:12' does not match format '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, strptime

I want to convert a French date with strptime.

`query_time=time.strptime(query_time, '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')`

is working on `1 mai 2020 10:21:26` but not on `30 avr. 2020 23:19:12`. I specified this line of code

`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')`.

The two dates have the same pattern, would you know why this does not work for the second?

Here is my code :

```
import re
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import locale


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')

# Fetch the html file
html_doc = googleData = open("./MonActivité_vr.html", encoding='utf8')


# Parse the html file
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.find_all("div", class_="outer-cell")
i = 0
j = 0

searchMonth = []
searchDay = []
searchYear = []
Recherche = []
URL= []

for row in rows: 

    i += 1
    print(f"Ligne {i} : ")

    cells = row.find_all("div", class_="content-cell")

    print(cells)

    # search / visited

    substring = "Vous avez consulté"

    if substring in str(cells[0]):

        print("Search")

    # SERP 
        print(cells[0])
        for a in cells[0].find_all('a', href=True):
            
            print(f"SERP : {a['href']}")#récupère le contenu de l'attribut href qui contient l'url du site consulté

            URL.append(a['href'])

            print("\n")

            print(f"KW : {a.string}")#récupère le contenu texte de la balise a => titre de la page consultée

            Recherche.append(a.string)

            

        # Time 16 mai 2020 à 16:50:52 CET
        
        query_time = ''.join(cells[0].find('br').next_siblings)
        print(query_time)

        # Removing timezone
        query_time = query_time.replace(" CET", "")
        query_time = query_time.replace(" à", "")
        print(query_time)
        #query_time = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(query_time, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S").timetuple())


        
        query_time=time.strptime(query_time, '%d %b. %Y %H:%M:%S')
        

        #print(query_time[0])
        
        searchDay.append(query_time[2])
        searchMonth.append(query_time[1])
        searchYear.append(query_time[0])


        print(query_time)
        print("\n")
        print(f"Date : {query_time}") 
        print("\n")
    
    else:
        print("Visited")

searchDict = {
        'URL':URL,
        'Recherche':Recherche,
        'searchDay':searchDay,
        'searchMonth':searchMonth,
        'searchYear':searchYear
        }

print(searchDict)

searchDF = pd.DataFrame(searchDict)

searchDF.to_csv(path_or_buf = 'D_searchData.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: For me, both works

Comment: Have you tried to add a dot after "%b" in the format string?

Comment: Could share the exact piece of code that you are running ?

Comment: @buran That is the shorten name of month in french, 05 is `mai`, 04 is `avril` whi becomes `avr.`, his code works for me

Comment: @azro for me both give a `ValueError`

Comment: @frederic have you set the locale as he did ?

Comment: @azro oops, no !

Comment: @azro with setting the locale, the first works for me and the second does

Comment: Don't know what to say more, it works for me, could be interesting for you to ensure that the data is exactly what you think. Like print it `print(">>" + query_time + "<<")` before the parsing to be sure there is space or other around

Comment: >>30 avr. 2020 23:19:12<< this is what i get @azro

Answer (score 0):

The first date is working, because `mai` is the full month name in french, but `avr` is a shortening (sorry for my bad english !) for `avril`. `30 avril 2020 23:19:12` works.

Comment: Nope too. The code works, because both `mai` and `avr.` are the shorten month name

Comment: @azro NO, i know french, and in french, `mai` is the FULL month name !

Comment: ... I **AM** french :D, `mai` is the full name, but it's also a 3-letter word, so it is ALSO the shorten name

Comment: @azro ok, mai is a special case then. But, the other months work only when they are written out.

Comment: it depends of the format you use `%b` is for shorten month, `%B` for full month. I'm sure of it, I tried the code and both works the same way for me

Comment: @azro weird, i tried it TOO and it gives me an error, equal if i use `%b` or `%B`.